Mac Terminal Screen Turns White
I'm experiencing an issue with my Mac Terminal where the screen frequently turns completely white (normally I have black background). And only a few lines at the bottom can display normally. Like this:
I didn't change any terminal profile and this issue just suddenly appears. Can anyone help?
System: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1

Have you noticed a pattern when this happens (for example, when running certain commands or when starting a remote sessions)? Does it stay white from that moment on or does it go back to a black background again? Which shell do you use (standard zsh, zsh or bash from homebrew)? Have you changed the advanced settings for your Terminal profile?

@jaume Thank you for your help. I use full screen mode and sometimes when I work on other app's screen for a while and switch back to the terminal screen I will find it turns white. And it does not go back to black background unless I restart it. I use zsh. I haven't changed the settings for my profile. But I do have a feeling this issue came up right after I upgraded my system.

Thank you for your answer. If you switch back to Terminal by selecting it from the Dock (instead of using Command-Tab), does it also turn white? If you don't use full screen mode but simply maximize the window, does it still happen?  Could you temporarily change your shell to bash (/bin/bash) (see https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/change-the-default-shell-trml113/mac for details) and see if that helps?
